# Weird shading issue in rendered mode

Tags: modeling, texturing

I have enabled smooth shading with and without auto smoothing, played with the normals, and tried a million other fixes but i after many hours of trying have made no process, i also searched online and didn't find any fixes to this issue

how can i fix this? any help is much appreciated! :)

[link for file here!](http://tempdrive.io/us/xnfuyhx0)

[image: weird triangle]

[image]

Comment: Wireframe please?

Comment: added the wireframe picture now

Comment: That’s not a full wireframe, go out of edit mode and enable wireframe under shading options.

Comment: I uploaded the file here so download it and view it, if you figure out a fix, lemme know :D thanks!
tempdrive.io/us/xnfuyhx0

Comment: Ngon is the reason, I believe, the one between inner and outer border edges. If you cut edges at least until it's convex and not a curvy one it would become better

Answer (score 2):

This is happening because of the ngons. If you look your model from side, you'll notice the face is not actually flat.
[image: side view of diagonal face]

There are two ways to fix them.

First(quick and dirty): use [Weighted normal modifier](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/modifiers/modify/weighted_normal.html) with `Keep Sharp` option enabled.
[image: Weighted normal applied]

The shading is better now. However, the topology issue stays still since the `Weighted normal modifier` changes **normals** only.

Second(better way to handle this issue): Recreate the model and use `Weighted normal modifier` on it. There are unnecessary bevels(like the "triangle-shaped" bevels that will create the shading issues on your model. Moreover, they will create unnecessary vertices.

If you want diagonal face with bevels, the topology should look like this:
[image: better topology]

And because this topology still makes ngon on the top(which will make shading issue too), use `Weighted normal modifier` to fix the shading issue.